# How to calculate an arithmetic conversion after converting from postfix to infix?

Tags: java, stack, infix-notation

I am writing a program that takes a postfix expression and converts it to an infix expression and outputs the result. This is the code I have written so far but I can't figure out how to do the calculation after the conversion.

```
public String convert(String postfix)
{
    Stack<String> variables = new Stack<>(); // declaring a new stack to 
    hold the variables
    for(int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = postfix.charAt(i);
        if(isOperator(c))
        {   
            String a = variables.pop();
            String b = variables.pop();                
            variables.push("("+a+c+b+")");
        }
        else
            variables.push(""+c);
    }
        return variables.pop();
}
```

I tried adding if/switch statements inside the function but I was getting the "Incompatible Stack and String error". I was trying to do something like:

```
if (variables == abc++)
{      
     (a + (b + c));
}
```

How can I go around doing this?

Comment: Imagine you didn't have to do the infix conversion and just to the maths.  How would you do it?

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is making an if else statement for each possibilities for the arithmetic equation

Comment: Well, give that a try, and if you get stuck, you can [edit] your question to be more specific with what you need.